# What happens when you call close() on a pipe file descriptor that was duplicated with dup2()?

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor, dup2

I have a question regarding file descriptors in Unix and C programming.

Let's say I use `pipe(fd)` to get file descriptor 3 and 4 for the pipe ends, 3 connects to the read end and 4 to the write end.

Now I use `dup2(fd[write_end],1)` to copy the descriptor of the write end (which was 4) to file descriptor 1 in my process. If I now do `close(fd[write_end])` will it close descriptor 1 or descriptor 4?

Comment: `write_end` will still be descriptor `4` (in your example).

Comment: Note that after the `dup2`, closing the pipe descriptor is _required_ to prevent extraneous/hanging file descriptors. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823093/fd-leak-custom-shell/52825582#52825582

Answer (score 1):

After a successful call to `dup2`, both file descriptors are valid.

When you then call `close(fd[write_end])`, because `fd[write_end]` is set to 4 this is the same as `close(4)`.  So file descriptor 1 remains open and usable.