# Minibash in C, problem making pipes between execvp and parent proccess

Tags: c, shell, environment-variables, pipe

I have to do this as a university project so I cant share the whole code, im sorry for that.

I have to create a function called "read" that enables the user to create new env variables, thats the easy part. The problem comes when I call that function as the last one of the commands array e.g  "ls | grep aux.txt | read a" this should give the env var A the value aux.txt,  the problem is that it get stuck in the

```
fgets(value, sizeof(value),stdin);
```

and I cant even recover the terminal.
Thanks in advance for the help if you need more info about the problem I will happily give it.

I can't reproduce exactly the main function as there are parts that are not mine but I hope this helps:

```
char **argvv;
int fd[2][2];
int pid;
int main(int argc, char ***argvv) {
argvv[0][0] = "echo";
argvv[0][1] = "elpmaxe";
argvv[1][0] = "rev";
argvv[2][0] = "read";
argvv[2][1] = "a";
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    pipe(fd[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        if(i ==0){
            dup2(fd[0][1], 1);
            fun_close(fd);
            execvp(argvv[0][0], argvv[0]);
        }
        if(i == 1){
            dup2(fd[0][0], 0);
            dup2(fd[1][1], 1);
            fun_close(fd);
            execvp(argvv[1][0], argvv[0]);
        }
    }else{
        if(i == 2){
            close(fd[0][1]);
            close(fd[0][0]);
            fun_read("read a", 3, fd[1]);
        }
    }
}
int corpse;
int status;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

return 0;
void fun_close(int **fd){
close(fd[0][0]);
close(fd[0][1]);
close(fd[1][0]);
close(fd[1][1]);
```

}

And here is the fun_read:

```
int fun_read(char **command, int argc, int fd[]){
char **env_varv;
char value[1024];
char last_var[1024];
long size = 0;
char *token;
    int status;
char *delim = " \t\n";

env_varv = malloc((argc-1) * sizeof(char *));

for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
env_varv[i-1] = strdup(command[i]);
wait(status);
}
if (fd[0] !=0){
    printf("%d\n", fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[0],0);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
}
fgets(value, sizeof(value),stdin);
int i = 0;
token = strtok(value, delim);
last_var[0] = '\0';
while(token != NULL){
    if(i == argc-2){
        while (token != NULL){
            strcat(last_var,token);
            setenv(env_varv[i],last_var,1);
            token = strtok(NULL,delim);
            strcat(last_var," ");
        }
    }
    else if (env_varv[i] != NULL){
        setenv(env_varv[i],token,1);
        token = strtok(NULL,delim);
        i++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

The program should put an envariomental variable called a with the value of example.

postscript: it seems like there is no problem if the previous command is a builtin "echo hi | echo hi2 | read a" $a=hi2

Sincerely I have tried all, changing the pipes doesnt work, changing fgets for read doesn't help either. Is the only part of the code I haven't been able to fix

Comment: See my answer: [fd leak, custom Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825582/5382650) for a working version. It may give you some ideas.

Comment: You wrote a similar, now-deleted, question yesterday — [Minibash in C, Problem making pipes between `execvp()` and parent process (minishell)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74650901/15168) for those with 20k+ reputation — with the same disclaimer.  I noted then that: We can't help debug invisible code. You need to produce an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  That's still true.

Comment: You say "if you need more info about the problem I will happily give it".  We need more information — in the form of an MCVE.  You have to do work to create the MCVE (especially approximating 'minimal'), but it is necessary for you to get much help at all.  Your `read` command is built into your shell, is it not?  It is crucial that you show the other code.  Your question title mentions `execvp()` but the code doesn't show any use of `execvp()`, which alone makes the question puzzling.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I hope this is enough, sorry for the inconvenience, im a new user and i have never made a question involving a lot of code so its difficult for me to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fragment of code shows some problems:

```c
char ***argvv;
int fd[2][2];
int pid;
int main(int argc, char ***argvv) {
argvv[0][0] = "echo";
argvv[0][1] = "elpmaxe";
argvv[1][0] = "rev";
argvv[2][0] = "read";
argvv[2][1] = "a";
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    pipe(fd[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        if(i ==0){
            close(fd[0][0]);
            close(fd[1][1]);
            close(fd[1][0]);
            dup2(fd[0][1], 1);
            execvp(argvv[0][0], argvv[0]);
        }
        if(i = 1){
            close(fd[0][1]);
            close(fd[1][0]);
            dup2(fd[0][0], 0);
            dup2(fd[1][1], 1);
            execvp(argvv[1][0], argvv[0]);
        }
        if(i = 2){
            close(fd[0][1]);
            close(fd[0][0]);
            close(fd[1][1]);
            dup2(fd[1][0], 0);
            fun_read("read a", 3, fd[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Rule of Thumb

You aren't closing enough pipe file descriptors in any of the processes.

If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`.

---

#### Other comments on the use of pipes

If the parent process will not communicate with any of its children via
the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe early
enough (before waiting, for example) so that its children can receive
EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on
write), rather than blocking indefinitely.
Even if the parent uses the pipe without using `dup2()`, it should
normally close at least one end of the pipe — it is extremely rare for
a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.

Note that the `O_CLOEXEC` option to
[`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
and the `FD_CLOEXEC` and `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` options to `fcntl()` can also factor
into this discussion.

If you use
[`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and its extensive family of support functions (21 functions in total),
you will need to review how to close file descriptors in the spawned process
([`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose.html),
etc.).

Note that using `dup2(a, b)` is safer than using `close(b); dup(a);`
for a variety of reasons.
One is that if you want to force the file descriptor to a larger than
usual number, `dup2()` is the only sensible way to do that.
Another is that if `a` is the same as `b` (e.g. both `0`), then `dup2()`
handles it correctly (it doesn't close `b` before duplicating `a`)
whereas the separate `close()` and `dup()` fails horribly.
This is an unlikely, but not impossible, circumstance.

---

#### Analyzing your code

The parent process has the pipes open; if the commands are reading from the pipes, they won't get EOF until the parent process closes them.  Although you close most of the pipes in the child processes, you don't close those that you duplicate to the standard I/O channels — and yet that is required too.

Note that `if (i = 1)` should be `if (i == 1)`, and `if (i = 2)` should be `if (i == 2)`.  The first of those bugs prevents your `fun_read()` from being invoked — which is why it isn't responding.  Using diagnostic printing to standard error would confirm that `fun_read()` is never called.

So, at bare minimum, you need to have code like this:

```c
char ***argvv;
int fd[2][2];
int pid;

int main(int argc, char ***argvv)
{
    argvv[0][0] = "echo";
    argvv[0][1] = "elpmaxe";
    argvv[1][0] = "rev";
    argvv[2][0] = "read";
    argvv[2][1] = "a";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pipe(fd[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                dup2(fd[0][1], 1);
                close(fd[0][0]);
                close(fd[0][1]);
                close(fd[1][0]);
                close(fd[1][1]);
                execvp(argvv[0][0], argvv[0]);
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s\n", argvv[0][0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                dup2(fd[0][0], 0);
                dup2(fd[1][1], 1);
                close(fd[0][0]);
                close(fd[0][1]);
                close(fd[1][0]);
                close(fd[1][1]);
                execvp(argvv[1][0], argvv[0]);
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s\n", argvv[1][0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                dup2(fd[1][0], 0);
                close(fd[0][0]);
                close(fd[0][1]);
                close(fd[1][0]);
                close(fd[1][1]);
                fun_read("read a", 3, fd[1]);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
    close(fd[0][0]);
    close(fd[0][1]);
    close(fd[1][0]);
    close(fd[1][1]);

    /* wait loop here - and not before */
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is important to handle failure to execute.  And error messages should be reported to standard error, not to standard output.

Given that the same sequence of 4 calls to `close()` is made 4 times, a function to do the job seems appropriate.  You could make it:

```
static inline void close_pipes(int fd[2][2])
{
    close(fd[0][0]);
    close(fd[0][1]);
    close(fd[1][0]);
    close(fd[1][1]);
}
```

There is a decent chance the compiler will inline the function, but it is easier to see that the same 4 descriptors are closed if one function always does the closing.  For bigger arrays of pipes (more processes), you'd have a loop inside the `close_pipes()` function with a counter as well as the array.

There are still some issues to be resolved, notably with the `fun_read()` function.  The `fd[1]` file descriptors were both closed, so passing those to `fun_read()` doesn't seem likely to be useful.  Since `fun_read()` is executed in a separate process, any changes made by `fun_read()` won't be reflected in the parent process.  There are probably other problems too.

AFAICT, on looking at `fun_read()` more closely, the `fd` argument should not be needed at all.  The paragraph of code:

```
if (fd[0] != 0) {
    printf("%d\n", fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[0], 0);
}
```

is not useful.  You've already redirected standard input so it comes from the pipe and then closed the pipe file descriptor.  This paragraph then changes standard input to come from the closed descriptor, which isn't going to help anything.  But none of this helps you with the fact that anything done by `fun_read()` is done in a child process of your shell, so the environment in the main shell is not going to be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jonathan, I am sorry about the coding errors. I rewrited the code so now the parent proces execute the fun_read without closing those pipes, also closed the rest of the pipes I opened in each process

Comment: also, the printf("%d\n", fd[0]); in the read was just for debugging