# C++ Calling another C++ function with popen and getting the output

Tags: c++, popen

I want to enter six integers, and that C++ program that is called returns some value (cout), but I find that the output is not printed until the program pclose(pipe). So that part of the fgets function in the middle doesn't get the value.
I wonder why？

```
string run_command_and_get_result(const char* command, int input1, int input2, int input3, int input4, int input5, int input6) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(command, "w");
    if (!pipe) {
        cerr << "Error: popen() failed!" << endl;
        return "";
    }

    fprintf(pipe, "%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6);

    fflush(pipe); 
    
    char buffer[MAX_RESULT_SIZE]; 
    string result = "";

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_RESULT_SIZE, pipe) != NULL) {
        cout << "1-EVERY RESULT- " << buffer << endl;
        result += buffer;
    }

    pclose(pipe); 
    
    cout << "2-EVERY RESULT- " << result << endl;
    return result;
}
```

at least I see where the problem is but I still think it is strange.

Comment: C is not C++, don't spam tags.

Comment: This function urgently needs `const std::vector<int>& input`.

Comment: Does the receiving program wait for a close signal on STDIN? You flush, but you do not indicate you're done sending.

Comment: The fgets() call shall be reading from stdin file descriptor, not from pipe.

Comment: Files opened by *popen* are only for reading or writing, but not both. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html . It's not possible to do what you want with *popen*.

Comment: I don't get where you are trying to go. Looks like we have a function writing into a pipe opened for writing and then the same function trying to read from the same pipe. Yah Pretty much what ^ just said.

Comment: Now I see popen cannot do both at the same time. But how should I realize this funcation?

Comment: You can use `pipe()`, `fork()` and `exec()` to achieve what you want. But it is a bit more involved.

Comment: You _can't_ use `popen` if you need _both_ output to and input from a given subprogram. `popen` is just a "convenience" function. Use a combo of `pipe`, `fork`, `dup2`, `exec*`, `wait`. For convenience, you could use `fdopen` on some of the `pipe` returned descriptors. There are _many_ examples on SO for doing this. A common one is doing a pipe in a shell. Here's one of mine: [fd leak, custom Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825582/5382650). You probably can simplify this because you only have a single stage ...